# Nearby cycle is tamely ramified?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, etale-cohomology

Let $S$ be a henselization of a closed point $s$ in a smooth algebraic curve $C$ over some finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Then we can consider nearby cycles over $S$. Let $s$ be the closed point of $S$ and $\eta$ be the generic point. Then $G=Gal(\overline\eta/\eta)$ is isomorphic to the Galois group of the local field at $s$.

For any scheme $X\to S$, the nearby cycle functor is a functor
$$R\Phi_X:D^b_c(X_{\eta},\mathbb{Q}_l)\longrightarrow D^b_c(X_{\bar s},\mathbb{Q}_l)$$
and carrying an action of $G$ compatible with the action on $X_{\overline s}$. Recall that we have an exact sequence
$$0\to I\to G\to Gal(\overline s/s)\to 1$$
where $I$ is the inertia subgroup, and $I$ carries a surjective homomorphism
$$t_l:I\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_l(1).$$
My question is: When is it true that the action of $G$ on $R\Phi_X$ factor through
$G\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_l(1)\rtimes Gal(\overline s/s)$?

Comment: You may want to look at [This article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.02860.pdf), especially Theorem 0.2.

Comment: @A.B.: Thank you! It seems that the book I'm reading has made a mistake on this.